# Looking for a funny and inspirational hindi movie

Tags: identify-this-movie, comedy, drama

Anyone could help me to find the movie I watch around 2007-2008.

All I remember to this movie are the following.

1. An actor role I think a civil engineer or contractor.
2. The girl he liked did not like him because is skin is dark so he paint his skin into white. Whenever he goes to work on site, he wears like a astronaut to cover all the body from sun in order not to get dark because he wanted to stay white for that girl.
3. I remember also he found a coin and this coin I think his inspiration. He start from 1 coin tell he become rich.

   4. I was on Singapore when I watch this movie around year 2007-2008

Please anyone knows this movie?

Comment: It is a tri-lingual movie (Tamil,Telugu & Hindi) from famous director Shankar (Also directed Robo) . I'm amazed that you don't know this movie. It is one of the best movies ever made by India

Comment: i watch this before in 2008 but only 70% of it.. i could even remember the title, but very inspiring though. and just finish watching it now 100%..year 2007 movie and its very professional how its made the effects. im pround of you people..

Comment: You should watch Aparachit & Bharateeyudu(The Indian) too by S Shankar, if you're looking for inspirational Indian movies. That director is a legend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The movie is *[Shivaji The boss(2007)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sivaji_(film))* with Rajnikanth as the lead role. It was a Tamil movie dubbed into Telugu, Hindi. You might have watched the [Hindi dubbed version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WKs6NmQibQY) of the movie.

In the movie, the hero is not a contractor or a civil engineer. He is a software professional. He was supervising a site where he was planning to building a hospital.

Rajnikanth was rejected by female lead Shriya initially because he was dark. But he was married to Shriya later.

The scene you are describing starts from [here](https://youtu.be/WKs6NmQibQY?t=3088).

This is the screenshot of the astronaut costume you are saying.

[image]

He has a 1 rupee coin. This is shown many times in the movie.

Comment: omg.. that movie i was looking for.. i keep searching it many times but still i cant find..thank you so much..

Comment: @FoRsStadis You are welcome. Keep visiting the site. You will like it.